# Why can't I delete this row?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, sql-delete

I am using ms 2007.
I tried to write the SQL code to delete the row for the person named "Ramoras Anne", hired on Nov 15, 1987 and whose job code is 501.

My table:

```
EMP_NUM EMP_LNAME   EMP_FNAME   EMP_INITIAL EMP_HIREDATE    JOB_CODE
101     News        John        G           11/8/2000       502
102     Senior      David       H           7/12/1989       501
103     Arbough     June        E           12/1/1996       500
104     Ramoras     Anne        K           11/15/1987      501
105     Johnson     Alice       K           2/1/1993        502
106     Smithfield  William                 6/22/2004       500
107     Alonzo      Maria       D           10/10/1993      501
108     Washington  Ralph       B           8/22/1991       501
109     Smith       Larry       W           7/18/1997       501
```

My code:

```
DELETE FROM EMP_1
WHERE EMP_LNAME='Ramoras' 
& EMP_FNAME='Anne' 
& EMP_HIREDATE='11/15/1987' 
& JOB_CODE='501';
```

But it didn't do anything when I run it.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And check the PK of `EMP_1`. If `EMP_NUM` is primary key. `delete from emp_1 where emp_num = 104;` will be sufficient.

Comment: My EMP_NUM is primary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may  be possible that u have stored your data in Upper case and since u are using ower case in delete query, no matches are found and hence nothing happened.

Try running the code using emp code

```
Delete from emp_1 where emp_num=104
```

Or you may first query your db using select and verify if you data is stored in upper case or lower case.